# Cómo mantener un String en un JTextField con .setText?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

he estado haciendo una calculadora con Jswing y use un TextField para simular lo qué sería el display del software.

Usé TextField.setText para qué cada vez qué se presione un botón, su valor se imprima en el Textfield pero cuando se presiona otro botón, este valor se cambia por el valor del último botón presionado. Cómo se podría mantener los dígitos en el display?

les adjunto el codigo:

```
private void Button8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        TextField.setText(Integer.toString(8));
    }                                       

    private void Button7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        
        TextField.setText(Integer.toString(7));
    }
```

Comment: Simplemente usa el método ``getText()`` y concatena el texto nuevo el JTextField.

Algo así

    ``field.setText(field.getText() + "new text");``

Comment: Gracias Broder! ya puse parte del código en donde hago los eventos de los botones :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtén el valor que se encuentra actualmente en tu JTextField mediante `textField.getText()` y concatena el nuevo valor, ejemplo:

```
textField.setText(textField.getText() + valorTexto);
```

---

de acuerdo a tu código sería:

```
private void Button8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    TextField.setText(TextField.getText() + Integer.toString(8));
}                                       

private void Button7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    TextField.setText(TextField.getText() + Integer.toString(7));
}
```